# Buscar registros de un objeto Json MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, json

Tengo el siguiente JSON almacenado en una columna de tipo JSON de una tabla en un esquema en Mysql 8.0.33:

```js
[
  {
    "1": {
      "number": 11,
      "checked": false
    },
    "2": {
      "number": 5,
      "checked": false
    },
    "3": {
      "number": 4,
      "checked": false
    },
    "4": {
      "number": 13,
      "checked": false
    },
    "5": {
      "number": 6,
      "checked": false
    },
    "6": {
      "number": 23,
      "checked": false
    },
    "7": {
      "number": 24,
      "checked": false
    },
    "8": {
      "number": 20,
      "checked": false
    },
    "9": {
      "number": 26,
      "checked": false
    },
    "10": {
      "number": 16,
      "checked": false
    },
    "11": {
      "number": 45,
      "checked": false
    },
    "12": {
      "number": 35,
      "checked": false
    },
    "13": {
      "number": 0,
      "checked": true
    },
    "14": {
      "number": 40,
      "checked": false
    },
    "15": {
      "number": 38,
      "checked": false
    },
    "16": {
      "number": 57,
      "checked": false
    },
    "17": {
      "number": 46,
      "checked": false
    },
    "18": {
      "number": 47,
      "checked": false
    },
    "19": {
      "number": 48,
      "checked": false
    },
    "20": {
      "number": 60,
      "checked": false
    },
    "21": {
      "number": 65,
      "checked": false
    },
    "22": {
      "number": 63,
      "checked": false
    },
    "23": {
      "number": 68,
      "checked": false
    },
    "24": {
      "number": 66,
      "checked": false
    },
    "25": {
      "number": 73,
      "checked": false
    }
  }
]
```

Lo que necesito hacer es recuperar todos los registros cuyo "number" sea igual a un determinado número, por ejemplo 11.
He probado con la siguiente consulta:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM bingo_db.tata_tables
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(numbers, '{"number": 11}', '$[0]."1"');
```

pero la misma me devuelve los registros que contienen ese número pero solo en la clave "1", dado que el número 11 podría estar en cualquiera de las otras llaves del 1 al 5, no me devuelve todos los registros correctamente.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM bingo_db.tata_tables
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(numbers, '{"number": 15}', '$[0].$');
```

Que he probado con la consulta anterior pero no obtengo nada.

¿Es posible realmente hacer esa consulta?

Answer (score 1):

Esta respuesta tiene una solución trivial y una solución complicada. No son intercambiables ni excluyentes. Simplemente aplican dependiendo de qué necesita hacer el OP en la práctica.

Vamos a simplificar un poco la estructura y renombrar las llaves para no confundirnos. Tienes una tabla que se ve más o menos como:

| id | documento_ejemplo |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"A": {"number": 4}, "B": {"number": 3}, "C": {"number": 1}}] |
| 2 | [{"Y": {"number": 6}}, {"U": {"number": 2}, "V": {"number": 4}}] |
| 3 | [{"Q": {"number": 6}, "S": {"number": 1}}, {"L": {"number": 8}}] |
| 4 | [{"D": {"number": 3}, "E": {"number": 2}, "P": {"number": 8}}] |
| 5 | [{"F": {"number": 3}}, {"R": {"number": 7}}, {"S": {"number": 9}}] |

Esto es:

- Tiene un campo JSON que llamaremos `documento_ejemplo`
- El cual contiene un array de largo N
- cuyos items son objetos
- cuya estructura es `<llave, tupla>`
- donde `llave` es un string cualquiera
- donde `tupla` es un objeto que tiene una llave `number` asociada a un valor numérico. Puede tener otras llaves, da igual.

### Solución trivial

Si tu pregunta es cómo obtener los registros que contienen `{"number": 4}` sin saber en qué posición del array figura el item, ni bajo qué llave del ítem aparece el valor buscado, tienes que preprocesar un poco la información, porque JSON_CONTAINS no va a desanidar la información recursivamente:

```
SELECT id,
  JSON_EXTRACT(documento_ejemplo,'$[*].*') valores
  FROM ejemplo_tabla
  WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_EXTRACT(documento_ejemplo,'$[*].*'),'{"number": 4}')
```

Entrega

| id | documento_ejemplo |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"A": {"number": 4}, "B": {"number": 3}, "C": {"number": 1}}] |
| 2 | [{"Y": {"number": 6}}, {"U": {"number": 2}, "V": {"number": 4}}] |

---

### Solución complicada

Si lo que quieres es obtener el objeto `<llave, tupla>` que calzó, eso es bastante más complicado. Necesitas crear un objeto nuevo a partir del existente (o "podar" la info existente) Pero... se puede? Por supuesto que se puede, querido lector.

##### Tabla Items

Usando la función [JSON_TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html) podemos enumerar   el contenido de `documento_ejemplo`. La primera enumeración que necesitamos es la que recorre el array. Esta subquery se llamará `tabla_items`

```
select id, item_id, item
from ejemplo_tabla
         join json_table(documento_ejemplo,
             '$[*]' columns (item_id FOR ORDINALITY ,
              item JSON path '$'
                 )
    ) items
```

La salida (pongo un par de registros solamente) son los items del array

| id | item_id | item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | {"A": {"number": 4}, "B": {"number": 3}, "C": {"number": 1}} |
| 2 | 1 | {"Y": {"number": 6}} |
| 2 | 2 | {"U": {"number": 2}, "V": {"number": 4}} |
| 3 | 1 | {"Q": {"number": 6}, "S": {"number": 1}} |

##### Tabla llaves

A partir de ese JSON_TABLE yo genero otro JSON_TABLE para una segunda enumeración, esta vez sobre las llaves del objeto. (yo las conozco, y puedo obtenerlas programáticamente usando JSON_KEYS, pero necesito que se genere una fila por cada llave) esta subquery se llamará `tabla_llaves` y su gracia es que tiene la información del id en la tabla original, la posición del item, y el nombre de la llave. **Con estos últimos dos yo puedo, además, computar el `json_path`**

```
     SELECT id,
            item_id,
            llave,
            concat('$[', item_id - 1, '].', llave) as json_path
      from tabla_items JOIN JSON_TABLE(
             json_keys(item), '$[*]' COLUMNS (
                 llave CHAR(1) PATH '$'
             )
      ) letras
```

| id | item_id | llave | json_path |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A | $[0].A |
| 1 | 1 | B | $[0].B |
| 1 | 1 | C | $[0].C |
| 2 | 2 | U | $[1].U |
| 2 | 2 | V | $[1].V |
| 2 | 1 | Y | $[0].Y |

##### Resultado Final

Con el json_path puedo crear un objeto JSON nuevo (que no es lo mismo que filtrar uno existente) mostrando la coincidencia:

```
 select id,
   item_id,
   llave,
   json_path, 
   JSON_OBJECT(llave, JSON_EXTRACT(documento_ejemplo, json_path)) objeto
 from tabla_llaves
     join ejemplo_tabla USING (id)
```

| id | item_id | llave | json_path | objeto |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A | $[0].A | {"A": {"number": 4}} |
| 1 | 1 | B | $[0].B | {"B": {"number": 3}} |
| 1 | 1 | C | $[0].C | {"C": {"number": 1}} |
| 2 | 2 | U | $[1].U | {"U": {"number": 2}} |
| 2 | 2 | V | $[1].V | {"V": {"number": 4}} |
| 2 | 1 | Y | $[0].Y | {"Y": {"number": 6}} |

En este punto ya es trivial filtrar cuáles registros tienen coincidencia, añadiendo simplemente

```
where
  JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(documento_ejemplo,json_path),'$.number')=4
```

Cuyo resultado es

| id | item_id | llave | json_path | objeto |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A | $[0].A | {"A": {"number": 4}} |
| 2 | 2 | V | $[1].V | {"V": {"number": 4}} |

Que cuadra con el resultado que obtuvimos al principio de esta respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Una opción es usar el operador [`LIKE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like), así:

```sql
SELECT numbers
FROM `tata_tables`
where numbers LIKE '%"number": 11%'
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u1kjiTeWY4zfgkTpQYWyEd/0)

Answer (score 0):

Para probar que existe un valor específico (ej. 11):

```
SELECT *
  FROM bingo_db.tata_tables
  WHERE 11 member of( numbers->'$[*].*.number' )
```

Primero extraemos un arreglo con los valores de `number` y usamos el operador [`member of`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_member-of) para evaluar si el valor (11) se encuentra en dicho arreglo.